# Integral curve for vector field tangent to sphere

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $S^1$ be the unit sphere $x_1^2+x_2^2=1$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and let $X=S^1\times S^1\in\mathbb{R}^4$ with defining equations $f_1=x_1^2+x_2^2-1=0, f_2=x_3^2+x_4^2-1=0$. The vector field $$w=x_1\frac\partial{\partial x_2}-x_2\frac\partial{\partial x_1}+\lambda\left(x_4\frac\partial{\partial x_3}-x_3\frac\partial{\partial x_4}\right)$$ ($\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$) is [tangent to $X$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/557698/restriction-of-vector-field-tangent-to-sphere) and hence defines by restriction a vector field $v$ on $X$. What are the integral curves of $v$?

At a point $p=(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\in X$, we have $v(p) = (p, (-x_2,x_1,\lambda x_4,-\lambda x_3))$.

The definition of an integral curve is the following:

A $C^{\infty}$ map $\gamma:(a,b)\rightarrow X$ is an integral curve of $v$ if, for $c\in (a,b)$ and $p=\gamma(c)$, $$v(p)=\left(p,\dfrac{d\gamma}{dt}(c)\right)$$

So we must have $$\dfrac{d\gamma(c)}{dt}=(-x_2,x_1,\lambda x_4,-\lambda x_3)$$

How can we solve for $\gamma$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, pick an initial point $\gamma(0)$. Your formula then also gives you the initial tangent of the curve $\gamma'(0)$.

Write $\gamma(t) = [\gamma_1(t) ,\gamma_2(t), \gamma_3(t), \gamma_4(t)].$ Then
$\frac{d}{dt}\gamma_1 = -\gamma_2$ and $\frac{d}{dt}\gamma_2 = \gamma_1$, so by substitution
$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\gamma_1 = -\gamma_1.$$

Can you solve this ODE, given the two initial conditions $\gamma_1(0)$ and $\gamma_1'(0) = -\gamma_2(0)$?

Can you work out the other three components?

Comment: It seems we have the solution $\gamma_1(t)=a\cos t+b\sin t$, $\gamma_2(t)=-a\sin t+b\cos t$, $\gamma_3(t)=c\cos(\lambda t)+d\sin(\lambda t)$, $\gamma_4(t)=-\lambda c\sin(\lambda t)+\lambda d\cos(\lambda t)$, for any constants $a,b,c,d$, right?

Comment: No, not any constants. The starting point must be on the manifold.